# Join tables with table name and column names only in JPA, Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Join tables with table name and column names only in JPA, Hibernate.

I have two entities users (in UserService) and addresses (in AddressService), now I want join address table to users table without using users entity but just using the users table and user_id as foreign key.

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "users", schema = "security", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }) })
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "user_id" })
public class User implements Serializable {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;
private String email;
private String password;

//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "address", schema = "account")
@SecondaryTable(name = "users", schema = "account", pkJoinColumns = { @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id") })
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id" })
@DynamicUpdate
public class AddressModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @Embedded
    private Address address;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "users", schema = "account", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id"))
public Long user_id;  // this is the primary key in users table 
                      // and want to make foreign key in addresses table
```

These two entitites are in two different RESTful web services. How can I join these two columns without creating the Entities or having the dependency ?

Comment: What is supposed to come out of this? you join the table, but don't want to get the entities, so what should be the result?

Comment: Why is there a ManyToOne annotation on a Long field? All JPA docs would tell you simply enough that a relation is of an entity type. If that "user_id" represents a User then put a field of type User. Object-orientation can't get simpler